# JS detect textfield change

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
<input type='text' id='id1' onkeydown='dynamic(this)' value='surya' />
<input type='text' id='id2' onkeydown='dynamic(this)' value='surya@email' />
<input type='text' id='id3' value='' />
<input type='submit' id='send' />
</form>
```

I want to show on 'id3' information about change data on id1 and id2 ?

if 'id1' change lets 'id3' value 'name'
if 'id2' change lets 'id3' value 'email'
if 'id1' and 'id2' change lets 'id3' value 'name;email'

http://jsfiddle.net/gegLfjLx/1 maybe a better solution for not depending on id

Comment: So where's your code.

Comment: trouble with understsanding rules. the code already post

Comment: @­SuryaTanamas - By code I mean is there any attempt at solving this problem made by you that you can share?

Comment: I just thinking using js, using normal comparasion

Comment: Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gegLfjLx/ Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: thanks that so helpful. But it no need onchange or similar

Comment: Yeah I did not use any inline event, just to separate script from markups.

Comment: ok that so helpful how about using array of id

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: something like auto create id like reloc1,reloc2,reloc3 etc

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `id` if you don't really want them: http://jsfiddle.net/gegLfjLx/1/

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/SuryaTanamas/gegLfjLx/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  (tested on http://jsfiddle.net/ruapce/9raLrz2f/1/):

```
var res='';
$('#id1,#id2').on('keyup',function(){ 
res=$('#id3').val(); 
if($(this).attr('id')=='id1'&& (res.indexOf('name')==-1))
    res+= (res=='')?'name':';name';   
 else if($(this).attr('id')=='id2'&& (res.indexOf('email')==-1))
  res+=(res=='')?'email':';email';
$('#id3').val(res);
});
```

Not sure this matches your sceneriao. Make necessary change for your sceneriao.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 .live can be replaced with .on

Comment: i don't so happy using jquery lug-in

Comment: how about not depending on id, to catch any name on form

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.

```
element.addEventListener('input', function() { /*...*/ }, false);
```